# Derivative of inverse matrix

Tags: matrices, inverse

Suppose $\Omega \left( \mathbf{\alpha }\right) $ is a $T\times T$ full rank
matrix where $\mathbf{\alpha }$ is a $p\times 1$ vector, then what's the
exact expression for $\frac{\partial \Omega ^{-1}\left( \mathbf{\alpha }%
\right) }{\partial \mathbf{\alpha }^{\prime }}?$ If $\mathbf{\alpha }$ is a
scalar, then
$$
\frac{\partial \Omega ^{-1}\left( \alpha \right) }{\partial \alpha }=-\Omega
^{-1}\frac{\partial \Omega ^{-1}\left( \alpha \right) }{\partial \alpha }%
\Omega ^{-1},$$
but any reference for the case of $\mathbf{\alpha }$ is a vector? Thanks!

Comment: I assume the $^{-1}$ refers to the matrix inverse, in which case what about taking the gradient of $\Omega^{-1}(\alpha)\Omega(\alpha)$? Btw, is there a $-$ sign missing in your equation for the scalar case?

Comment: Thanks, I have revised the typo. the −1 do refers to the matrix inverse. Could you please be more specific about your approach? Thanks

Comment: Let $F(\alpha) = \Omega(\alpha)\Omega^{-1}(\alpha)$ and notice that $F(\alpha)\equiv I$ (the identity matrix). Then take the Jacobian on the left (which gives you the $0$ matrix, since $F$ is constant) and on the right using the product rule, and you're pretty much done..